# Multiple `title` testing with `eslint` - is there a way

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc

I have 2 titles each one of them following. but my `eslint` with angular not throws the error. do i require any more config to be added with my `..eslintrc.json` file. as well do i need to add all the rules by manually alwasy?

here is my cofig file:

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-alt-text": "error",
        "@angular-eslint/prefer-on-push-component-change-detection": "error",
        "@angular-eslint/no-pipe-impure": "error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

html:

```
<app-forecast></app-forecast>
<app-notification-list></app-notification-list>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Title one</h1>
    <h1>Title two</h1> //no error
    <img [src]="'https://picsum.photos/200/300'" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <app-na-article-list></app-na-article-list>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

eslint checks only for linting issue. The above html code is correct and will not throw any error.

Comment: Is there any way to extend this?